# Underwater Property Simulation with ROS2 e.g Particle Plume

Tags: gazebo, ros-humble, underwater, auv, usv

I want to develop and test adaptive path planning algorithms for AUVs or also USVs.

So far I did this in ROS1 with the [UUV Simulator](https://github.com/uuvsimulator) and especially the [uuv_plume_simulator](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_plume_simulator).

Now I am looking for ways to do this in ROS2.

I managed to get a simulation of an AUV working with ROS2 Humble and Gazebo Ignition but I couldn't find a solution comparable to the UUV Plume Simulator.

Are there Gazebo (Ignition/Garden/Harmonic) Plugins or Projects that already deal with the simulation of the distribution of water properties like salinity/turbidity/temperature or the simulation of freshwater/hotwater/oil/particle spill or plumes?
Ideally these properties would be also influenced by currents.

So far i only came across the [EnvironmentPreload](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1EnvironmentPreload.html) Plugin for Gazebo Harmonic but it seems to only offer the a static distribution of values.

Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did a port of the UUV Plume Simulator Package to Ros2 and it is available here:

https://github.com/tiko5000/uuv_plume_simulator_ros2